# Nuxt - can i run client side code from a middleware in Universal mode?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working on a universal Nuxt app that uses the standard Django session authentication.
I need to restrict some pages in my project to logged in users only, so i decided to use a middleware.

The problem with the middleware is that it will run from server side, so it will always return `False` to the user even when the user is logged in, since it doesn't send any cookie in the request. This happens only when i refresh page or when i navigate directly to it, not when i navigate from another page to a restricted page, that's because in that case the middleware is executed client side and not server side.

Is there any way i can "force" the following code to run client side instead of server side from the middleware? Or do i have to look for another solution?

```
export default async function (context) {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/checkAuth',
    withCredentials: true,
  }).then(function (response) {
    //Check if user is authenticated - response is always False
  }).catch(function (error) {
    //Handle error
  });
}
```

I tried to do the same with `nuxtServerInit` but the outcome is the same. If i run that code in the `beforeCreate` block from the page it will first load the page and then execute the request, which works but it's quite ugly since the user will see the page for a second before being redirected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is another way around this.
First You need to run your middleware code only on the client side.

```
export default async function (context) {
   if(process.client) {
      // your middleware code here
   }
}
```

Now you just have to take care of the first load of your application. you can create a plugin that only runs on the client-side and use the middleware code inside the plugin.
for running the plugin only on the client use the mode key word like this.
this is the nuxt.config.js:

```
plugins: [ 
    { src: '~/plugins/client-only.js', mode: 'client' }, // only on client side 
  ]
```

Comment: I guess you can check the route and then run the code or see if the auth check is done then don't run the script.

Comment: Thank you! I created the plugin, but it seems to run twice, one time from server side and another time from client side

Comment: I think you can use process.client to run the code in your plugin only on the client-side.

Comment: I have an issue with nuxt 3, where do I place router middleware in nuxt 3? @mostafa

Comment: currently, there is only a server middleware section in Nuxt3 documentation. As The Nuxt team suggested you should use the Nuxt bridge so you can use Nuxt 2 features without experiencing breaking changes. With Nuxt Bridge you place middleware same as before (like version 2) and your app should work while you have the new Nuxt3 features.
also checkout the router middleware part for version 2:
https://nuxtjs.org/examples/middlewares/router/

Comment: There is a "client" Middleware directory in Nuxt 3: https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware