# Route guard not working when target blank is used on nuxt-link

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am trying to use router guard in nuxt middleware, which seems to work fine, but when the `nuxt-link` has an attribute of `target="blank"`, the middleware doesn't seems to work.
Example of the middleware

```js
export default function({ app }) {
  app.router.beforeEach((to, from=>{
    console.log({to, from})
  })
}
```

The nuxt-link tag is like this

```
<nuxt-link to="/about" target="_blank">About</nuxt-link>
```

Comment: Is your project has serve-rside rendering? If so, then the middleware runs on server on page load! You can modify this middleware to only work on client site or turn the server-side rendering by `ssr: false` in your `nuxt.config.js` file [middleware](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/middleware/)

Comment: is there a way to make the only the middleware client-side, I have some other middleware that must be run server-side.

Comment: take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67035624/15896638)